# Does BTCE API have a fast ticker?

Tags: btce

I think the title is pretty self explanatory. I know that MtGox has a fast ticker, so I was just wondering if BTCE had a similar function. 
Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a ticker that is constantly up to date then yes. See [here](https://hdbtce.kayako.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/28/4/public-api) .
 As far as a way for pulling that data here is a php example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021266/parsing-json-data-from-a-remote-server